# How to create a video from a series of images with transition

Tags: java, android

I want to create a video from a series of images and add a transition between the images (e.g., fade in and fade out). I’m looking for a Java solution and not a C++ one (FFmpeg or anything else).

I checked out JCodec and MediaCodec, but none of those support image transitions.

Comment: Do the image transitions have to be fast? (24 fps? 60? 1?)

Comment: @Steven i dont know what you mean by fast, but i want to create something like this(created by slideshow app): [link]https://youtu.be/plC6dNq79Zc

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried it with OpenCV for Java? OpenCV offers almost everything you need for such a task. To the transitions you would have to worry about then manually with image blending. But that can be solved with OpenCV too. Just take a look at the [documentary](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

**EDIT:**

It looks like the Java API lacks the appropriate module that can encode a sequence of images. You can fade images in any case. Take a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html). This means you would have to crossfade the images with OpenCV and then use another API (e.g. jcodec) to make a video from the images you create.

Comment: Thank you lukas! OpenCV just help me for creating the transition or it can give a video output too?

Comment: thanks for your answer, i didn't use OpenCv yet but i don't think it can create something like this: https://youtu.be/plC6dNq79Zc by the way i will work on that tonight, thanks

Comment: @abdollah Of course, something like this is possible with OpenCV. But you have to do a considerable amount of matrices and mathematics and only partially overlay the images or make perspective transformations. The speed at which the individual animations are carried out ultimately only indicates how many images are output during the respective transformation. To put it simply, you either make 10 images (fast transition) or 30 images (slow transition) from two images. But doing that programmatically is usually too much for the frame, because there are ready-to-use video editing programs